# F# Sequences, Lists and Arrays

Tags: f#, seq

Suppose I have a list of elements of type `'a`, i.e.;

```
let mylist: 'a list = ...
```

and a function f of type `'a -> 'b`;

```
let f: 'a -> 'b = ...
```

Now I want to use `f` transform `mylist` into a `'b array`.

Is the following:

```
mylist |> List.map f |> Array.ofList
```

improved upon performance-wise and memory-wise by the following:

```
mylist |> List.toSeq |> Seq.map f |> Array.ofSeq
```

?

Comment: Why don't you measure it?

Comment: @Enigmativity I wish I knew how to, reliably that is...

Comment: Try starting with `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your use-case, ìe how big is `myList`? However, in general `Seq` in F# is slow and wasteful with memory. Luckily, for the most time that doesn't matter as we usually only have to avoid "truly awful performance" while "mediocre performance" is usually good enough.

I haven't measured it (shame) but from my experience in most cases this would perform the better than the examples by OP

```
mylist |> Array.ofList |> Array.map f
```

Convert from list to Array ASAP and then map the Array (Arrays are for sequential access one of the more efficient structures in .NET).

In some rare scenarios where storing an intermediate array value would cause memory to be swapped to disk I suppose using `Seq` could help, however in those scenarios why would we be using `List<_>` as that is wasteful with memory compared to `Array<_>` (unless we can make use of tail reuse)?

There are libraries in .NET that has `Seq` like properties but still provides decent performance like: https://github.com/nessos/Streams

Church-encoded lists or transducers are also quite performant while avoiding intermediate array values.